# Decreasing series and condensation test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n \downarrow0 $ ($a_n$ is decreasing and converges to 0).

Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \min (a_n,\frac1n)=\infty$

(We have a hint to use the Cauchy condensation test.)

Now I may be reading this wrong but we are asked to show that the 'smaller' of the two goes to infinity. We know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$ from the assumption and we also know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n=\infty$ since we use it in convergence tests. So how do you approach this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see with the given hint:

Since $\;\min\left(a_n,\frac1n\right)\downarrow 0\;$, the Condensation Test tells us our series converges iff

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\min\left(2^na_{2^n},1\right)\;\;\text{converges}\ldots\ldots$$

But $\;\min(2^na_{2^n},1)\le 1\;$ , so....

Comment: But the condensation test doesn't have any criterion with more or less than 1... So I don't get it.

Comment: The condensation test is for the series of $\;\min(a_n,1/n)\;$ . Now, in order to find out what happens with the condensed series we use the comparison test...

Comment: You mean the comparison test for $\min(2^na_{2^n},1)$ right ?

Comment: Yes, **after** I apply the condensation test to the original $\;\min...\;$, and then to the result, which is what you wrote, I apply the comparison test.

Comment: So now all that is left is to compare this: $2^na_{2^n}$ if $a_n$ is decreasing and approaches zero then so is this. So I can compare it to this for example $\frac1{n^2}$ ?

Comment: But I showed you that we can compare it with the divergent series $\;\sum 1\;$ ...!

Comment: Wait what ?! $\sum 1$ is diverging?! (isn't that equal to just 1 ?) Also, I thought this was trivial and thought to split it to cases, first where it's equal to 1 and second where it's less than 1.

Comment: No...! $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{(1+1+\ldots+1)}_{n\;\text{times}}=\infty\;,\;\;\text{of course}$$

Comment: To apply the Condensation test $\min(a_n,1/n)$ must be non increasing.

Comment: min(a(n), 1/n) is non-increasing. To see this we consider two cases:

Comment: case 1: a(n+1) >= 1/(n+1)

Comment: case 2: a(n+1) < 1/(n+1)

Comment: both cases lead to the result and the details are quite easy to fill

Comment: @DonAntonio why we couldn't do the comparison test from the begining ? I mean we know that $\sum \frac1n \to \infty$.

Comment: Since min(a(n),1/n) is not always greater than or equal to a(n) for all n's so the estimate Sigma(min(a(n),1/n) >= Sigma(a(n)) may not hold. But the left sum can still tend to infinity slower than the right sum.

Comment: You can use the comparison test for the series Sigma(max(a(n),1/n)).

Answer (score 0):

Let A = {n in N :  a(2^n) > 1/2^n} ( read: a sub 2^n ). Then A is a subset of the natural numbers N. So there are two cases to consider:
1) A is finite: 
This means A = empty or N - A is countably infinite. For if A = empty, then a(2^n) <= 1/2^n ( read a sub 2^n ) for all n. Thus min(a(2^n), 1/2^n) = a(2^n) and Sigma(2^n*min(a(2^n),1/2^n) = sigma(2^n*a(2^n)) = infinity by Cauchy condensation test since Sigma(a(n)) = infinity.  If A is not empty and also finite, let A = { n(1), n(2),...., n(k)} then Let m = Max{n(1),..,n(k)} + 1, then Sigma(2^n*min(a(2^n),1/2^n)) = Sigma(2^n*min(a(2^n),1/2^n) (for n = 1 to m) + Sigma(2^n*a(2^n) (for n = m to infinity ) = M + infinity. Thus we have the conclusion by Cauchy condensation test again.
2) A is countably infinite:
Then Sigma(2^n*min(a(2^n),1/2^n) >= Sigma(2^n*min(a(2^n),1/2^n) (for n's in A ) = Sigma(2^n*1/2^n) = Sigma(1) (for infinitely many 1's ) = infinity. So by Cauchy condensation test, the series Sigma(min(a(n),1/n) diverges.
We are done.

Comment: This is almost impossible to understand. Please do use LaTeX when posting here.

Comment: I wonder if we can attach pdf file here so I can retype it in MSWord and attach it here.

Comment: I think you better learn how to type LaTeX here. It's not hard at all and it renders the clearest, neatest stuff. Attached Filesa re not so welcome usually because of this reason.

Comment: You can just upload an image/screenshot either here or on imgur.

Comment: Many members just ignore image/screenshots linked to other sites...

Comment: @MatikKen if it's easier for you to use Word, you can just paste it to word, take a screenshot and upload it here, there's an option for it in the answer box.